# Wordpress permissions issue when trying to upload and atach file to post

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I'm having real headache with attaching photo to post in WordPress. Everything works perfectly when I'm logged in as an administrator. For other users (with edit_posts permission set), I'm getting

> **Sorry, you are not allowed to attach files to this post**

error. Checked if statement in the `wp_ajax_upload_attachment()` function and it reads the following:

```
if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
```

What I did to narrow down the issue was to concatenate piece of code to AJAX response:

```
'data'    => array(
                    'message'  => __( 'Sorry, you are not allowed to attach files to this post.' ).' '.print_r(current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ))
```

To my surprise value concatenated to response is 1. Now I'm thinking that maybe using print_r is messing up. Otherwise it means that current_user_can returns different value in second invocation. Checked POST data, also checked that `$post_id` has correct value.

Can anyone help me to figure out what is going on here?

Thanks,
Marcin

Comment: What is the user type you are using?

Comment: Are you hooking something?  Has the current user been instantiated at the hook you are using?

Comment: This is custom user type from 3rd party plugin. It has edit_posts and edit_other_posts. In addition same user is able to upload media in couple other places. I'm not using hook in this area. In this particular case media is uploaded with JS provided with the plugin which I use. Checked data send from the form, checked data in the backend and seems to be fine. Post_ID is correct, post was created by the user - there should be no problem with permissions, but for whatever reason current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id) return false.

Comment: **UPDATE** I was wrong current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id) returns false. So now I need to figure out why it is returning false. On daily basis I'm dealing with rather low level coding, still learning how to debug wordpress and php. Checked all plugins which are being used and found function using user_has_cap filter, maybe it is trying to fool me.